# 403 Error on REST call in SharePoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api, authentication

I have a list called Project Log on a sub-site which need to automatically copy any item created in it to another List on the parent site called Master Project Log. This has to be accomplished using the reproducible 2013 workflows.

So far, my workflow looks like the following:

**RequestHeader:**

- accept - string - application/json; odata=verbose
- content-type - string - application/json; odata=verbose
- content-length - string - 255

**Call REST API:**

```
POST https://[domain]/sites/T3W-PM/_api/contextinfo log to ResponseContent
```

Get `d/GetContextWebInformation/FormDigestValue` from `ResponseContent` (output to DigestID)

Running the workflow at this point completes successfully and returns the contents of `DigestID` which looks like this:

```
0xFB1B72F8971917CCCB3E605B397CC27ACB758650ACDB98A0848D1BC8CF5A861BD33A0EC0CF094F5D1C3188D842E470A46D25F6CA9780277A74C9AFCEB471423C,12 Aug 2019 09:55:53 -0000
```

This should be the `FormDigestValue`. I then pass that into the `RequestHeader` and run a second REST call to create the new list item:

**RequestHeader:**

- accept - string - application/json; odata=verbose
- content-type - string - application/json; odata=verbose
- X-RequestDigest - string - [workflow variable: DigestID]

**metadata:**

- type - string - SP.Data.ListItem

**RequestContent:**

- __metadata - dictionary - `<workflow variable: metadata>`
- Title - string - `<current project number>`

**Call REST API:**

```
POST https://[domain]/sites/T3WPM/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('[target list]')/items
```

The second REST call results in a **BadRequest error** in the workflow log. When I run the same parameters though Fiddler I get a 403 Forbidden error.

This should not happen as the account the workflow is running under is both an Owner with Full Control permissions and a Site Collection Administrator.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

In researching this I've seen some references to OAuth authorization but I don't know how to get the OAuth authentication token or if I actually need one.

Comment: Have you tried using [App step in workflow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-a-list-using-http-web-service-in-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/)?

Comment: I haven't but it shouldn't be necessary. Without the app step the workflow uses the initiator's permissions and the account it's running under is a Site Collection Administrator and in the Site Owners group. The lowest privileges that anyone accessing this site will have is Contribute which is more than enough to create new list items.

Answer (score 0):

The type for creating a new list item is not SP.Data.ListItem. It is actually based on the name of the list when it was created. You can find the correct type at this endpoint.

```
/_api/web/lists/'getbytitle('[target list]')/listItemEntityTypeFullName
```

It will be something like `SP.Data.TargetListListItem` (assuming you named the list *TargetList* when it was created.